# Creating a jar with a shell script inside it

Tags: java, shell, file, jar, resources

I trying to write a java class to execute a shell script with input parameters and pack everything under a jar and and on running the jar using jar command it should able to run the script. I've also used URI and Canonical path but my code is not able to find the script.

My Class and Script is in same package.

Please find my code below

```
String appid = args[0];

        System.getProperties();





        MFA obj = new MFA();


        File file = null;
        try {
            file = new File(obj.getClass().getResource("code/auth.sh").toURI());
        } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        String path=null;
        path = file.getAbsolutePath();



        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(path, appid);
         Process p = null;

            try {
                p = pb.start();

                BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));



                // read the output from the command
                System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
                String s = null;
                while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    System.out.println(s);
                }

                // read any errors from the attempted command

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

My code is throwing null pointer Exception.

======== UPDATE ==========

I eventually solved this problem. Shell cannot execute scripts within a JAR bundle, it's not about Java, but shell. I fixed this by doing the following:

Java has a createTempFile() method (with option to delete the file once the application has been terminated), invoke this, and write the file within the JAR bundle that you want to access to this temp file. You then have the shell script on the local filesystem, and are able to execute the script.

Comment: Hi -- this looks like a good question. Please edit the question and provide a complete code example (i.e. one that can be cut & pasted and will compile). Also provide the script you are trying to add to the jar, and the command line your are using to create the jar file. That will help this question to be answered. Thanks!